# Performance issue on XPS13 9300 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, performance, xps

I was using an XPS13 with ubuntu 18 without any trouble. I upgrade my Ubuntu to 20.04 release. Everything was running fine for the first month after some tricky process to fix the wifi. In my memory, the laptop was running like a charm. The only issue is that after the Ubuntu upgrade, my mousepad is very inaccurate. The problem is that for few months my laptop is very very slow.

I can work in a terminal but when I need to use a graphical feature everything is slow. Just the login process on the computer on the computer is a nightmare due to the input keyboard lag in the textbox. Even if the terminal is not to laggy, it is very slow to switch between two terminals (alt-tab). I just run the test, he took me almost 10 seconds to switch from my browser to my terminal...

I found several topic on this forum with performance issue with XPS13 but I was not able to fix my issue.

The gpu driver seems to be ok :

```
[arthur ] hwinfo --gfxcard
25: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)              
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: _Znp.M4DO9l_zkd2
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Device Name: "To Be Filled by O.E.M."
  Model: "Intel VGA compatible controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x8a52 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x096d 
  Revision: 0x07
  Driver: "i915"
  Driver Modules: "i915"
  Memory Range: 0x603c000000-0x603cffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x4000000000-0x400fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x4000-0x403f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 185 (25708746 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00008A52sv00001028sd0000096Dbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Primary display adapter: #25
```

I don't see any issue with gnome extension :

```
[arthur ] ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 nov.   5  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 mars  31 16:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 nov.   5  2020 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 janv.  9 17:39 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 déc.   3 12:17 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
[arthur ] ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell
total 16
drwx------  2 arthur arthur 4096 mai   17 15:15 .
drwx------ 26 arthur arthur 4096 mai   17 14:51 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 arthur arthur 1738 mai   17 15:15 application_state
-rw-rw-r--  1 arthur arthur    0 nov.   5  2020 gnome-overrides-migrated
-rw-rw-r--  1 arthur arthur  543 nov.   5  2020 notifications
[arthur ] [arthur ] ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 nov.   5  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 mars  31 16:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 nov.   5  2020 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 janv.  9 17:39 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 déc.   3 12:17 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

I don't see any particular trouble in htop.

Any suggestion to diagnostic the issue?
Can I roll back my ubuntu to 18 release without reinstalling everything?

Thanks,

Comment: Rolling back an OS is not likely unless you have been using a file system that allows snapshots. Are you using the Hardware Enablement kernel for your notebook?

Comment: @matigo I just check with hwe-support-status --verbose. yes it is !